# Rotativa.MVC load view from file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, rotativa

I am using Rotativa.MVC to generate PDF's from html. and it works fine.

What I am trying to do now is to extend the system so that the user can define its own views (razor cshtml files) that then can be used as templates:

I extended the class that Rotativa.MVC uses as ViewEngineResult but the system is complaining that it can't find the view in that location even do the file exsists and the path is correct

```
public class myViewAsPdf : ViewAsPdf
{
    private string _plugin;

    public myViewAsPdf(string viewName, object model)
    {
        base.ViewName = viewName;
        base.Model = model;
    }

    public void InitPlugin(string name)
    {
        _plugin = name;

    }

    protected override System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineResult GetView(System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext context, string viewName, string masterName)
    {
        var viewPath = GetPluginPath(_plugin,"Views");
        if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(viewPath))
        {
            return base.GetView(context, viewName, masterName);
        }
        ViewEngineResult ret = new ViewEngineResult(new string[] { String.Format("{0}\\{{0}}.cshtml", viewPath) });
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Caller function:

```
    public static byte[] GeneratePdf(this HttpControllerContext context, Controller controller, object model, string viewName, string fileName, string plugin = null)
    {
        var cnt = new myViewAsPdf(viewName, model) { FileName = fileName };
        cnt.InitPlugin(plugin);
        return cnt.BuildPdf(controller.ControllerContext);
    }
```